# positioning elements with col-push and col-pull boostrap 3

Tags: html, css, grid, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to put the text above the image when it is a mobile viewport i am using twitter bootsrap 3 helper classes col-push and col-pull but i can get it working.

This is mostly like my html, i like to have a row with three span4. Each span4 need to have an image and a text associated at the bottom of the image. When the viewport is mobile i need to switch the position of the text for the position of the image (text top, image bottom).

I cant figure it out.. anyone can help me explaining how really col-push and col-pull works or what i missed to get this working?

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
        <head>
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/3.0.1/normalize.css">
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        </head>
        <body>
    <div class="container row">
        <div class='col-lg-4'>
            <a class="" href="#" target="_self">
                <img src="https://d13yacurqjgara.cloudfront.net/users/31371/screenshots/269938/400x300.png">
            </a>
            <span class=''>Put some text in this area</span>
        </div>
        <div class='col-lg-4'>
            <a class="" href="#" target="_self">
                <img src="https://d13yacurqjgara.cloudfront.net/users/31371/screenshots/269938/400x300.png">
            </a>
            <span class=''>Put some text in this area</span>
        </div>
        <div class='col-lg-4'>
            <a class="" href="#" target="_self">
                <img src="https://d13yacurqjgara.cloudfront.net/users/31371/screenshots/269938/400x300.png">
            </a>
            <span class=''>Put some text in this area</span>
        </div>
    </div>

        </body>
    </html>
```

Thanks so much.

Comment: I'm not a bootstrap user but what you're looking for would require some JS or use of the flexible box model...or some complex and hairy css using absolute positioning.

Comment: Yes, @Jbird is correct. Answer 1 by Shawn Taylor is a way to do this with the CSS built into Bootstrap. Pushes and pulls don't work vertically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can also do this without any custom CSS, but by repeating some of your markup and show/hiding it depending on device, using the `hidden-*/visible-*` classes:

**http://www.bootply.com/evXH6jijLe**

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="col-lg-4">
     <p class="visible-xs">Text Mobile 1</p>
        <img src="img.png">
     <p class="hidden-xs">Text Desktop 1</p>
    </div>
   <div class="col-lg-4">
     <p class="visible-xs">Text Mobile 2</p>
        <img src="img.png">
     <p class="hidden-xs">Text Desktop 2</p>
    </div>
   <div class="col-lg-4">
     <p class="visible-xs">Text Mobile 3</p>
        <img src="img.png">
     <p class="hidden-xs">Text Desktop 3</p>
    </div>
```

You may need to get more specific with which `hidden-*/visible-*` classes you use, but this will ultimately get it done.

Comment: I like how you were able to think of a one custom way of doing this definitely a valid way. Using the predefined tools inside bootstrap is a good strategy. I used the custom CSS because I prefer not duplicate elements. As a question have you implemented this way before, I'm curious to see a live example of this in action. Sorry for the comment I cannot find a PM option.

Comment: Adding to this answer, you could also utilize the RESS approach (responsive design with server side components) to deliver content based on the type of device requesting the page. Combining device detection WITH responsive design is a great way of avoiding extraneous markup AND optimizing page load time. When designing for mobile, performance has to be considered. http://www.lukew.com/ff/entry.asp?1392

Comment: @TheHamstring Shawn didn't think of this, it's the most commonly used solution to create the design pattern that the OP described. It's implemented in countless sites. In fact, look at the code on any typical responsive site and it's most likely utilized. It's de facto until flexible box model takes over the world.

Comment: @TheHamstring yeah, bootstrap is my preferred toolset, because I know it well. I know there are other solutions, and some better for various reasons. In this case the small load of duplicated markup seems reasonable. But then again, if there ends up being hundred of images/comment combos on the page, that's hundreds of extra lines of markup and another way might be advisable. Custom CSS would be my choice since it avoids duplication as well as server work.

Comment: @Jbird definitely outside my wheelhouse, but in many cases probably the best bet. That beig said, it's not that I didn't think of it, but that's not what was asked by OP.

Comment: I appreciate the responses you guys gave. It's helpful to learn different ways to approach a problem and find a solution!

Answer (score 2):

Col-push and col-pull allow you to horizontally position elements. Those elements positioning are still ultimately controlled by where they are in the DOM, unfortunately it will not affect vertical positioning. It looks like you want to have the text and the image swap. The way you can do this is switch your markup with the text on top because it is more likely to vary in vertical size than the image at desktop view..

When your site is in desktop view set the position of the anchor tag surrounding the image as absolute. Set the margin-top to the span that contains the text to push it below the image. When you hit your mobile breakpoint set the anchor position to a block and the remove the margin from the span.

Make sure the div containing these elements has a relative position so the images are positioned inside the container.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Shawn Taylor, I finally Bootstrap Grid working fully. Now all the items are on one row, when you look at your page from Desktop browser. For that to get working, I needed to change the Bootsrap stylesheet reference to: `href="http://getbootstrap.com/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"`. If you make your browser window smaller your items will stack up like when using mobile phone. However, I didn't get the push and pull working. Instead, I used Shawn Taylor's very  neat solution of hiding elements based on the viewport size; so now you should items stacked in the right order when you look that page on mobile device.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
        <head>
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/3.0.1/normalize.css">
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://getbootstrap.com/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"> 
        </head>
        <body>
     <div class="container">
    <div class="row">     
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 hidden-xs">
                    <a  href="#" target="_self">
                        <img src="https://d13yacurqjgara.cloudfront.net/users/31371/screenshots/269938/400x300.png">
                    </a>
                </div>
                 <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 hidden-xs">
                    Put some text in this area
                </div>
            </div>
             <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-12 hidden-lg hidden-md">
                    Put some text in this area
                </div>
                 <div class="col-xs-12 hidden-lg hidden-md">
                    <a  href="#" target="_self">
                        <img src="https://d13yacurqjgara.cloudfront.net/users/31371/screenshots/269938/400x300.png">
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 hidden-xs">
                    <a  href="#" target="_self">
                        <img src="https://d13yacurqjgara.cloudfront.net/users/31371/screenshots/269938/400x300.png">
                    </a>
                </div>
                 <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 hidden-xs">
                    Put some text in this area
                </div>
            </div>
             <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-12 hidden-lg hidden-md">
                    Put some text in this area
                </div>
                 <div class="col-xs-12 hidden-lg hidden-md">
                    <a  href="#" target="_self">
                        <img src="https://d13yacurqjgara.cloudfront.net/users/31371/screenshots/269938/400x300.png">
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 hidden-xs">
                    <a  href="#" target="_self">
                        <img src="https://d13yacurqjgara.cloudfront.net/users/31371/screenshots/269938/400x300.png">
                    </a>
                </div>
                 <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 hidden-xs">
                    Put some text in this area
                </div>
            </div>
             <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-12 hidden-lg hidden-md">
                    Put some text in this area
                </div>
                 <div class="col-xs-12 hidden-lg hidden-md">
                    <a  href="#" target="_self">
                        <img src="https://d13yacurqjgara.cloudfront.net/users/31371/screenshots/269938/400x300.png">
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
   </div>
        </body>
    </html>
```